# Problem with Citation Numbering

Tags: citing

I have problems with my cite numbering. For example the first citation in my document is number 6 which is numbered correctly in the bibliography but how can I change it to number 1,2,3 and so on as I use them in my document not as 6,4,12,1,4

I am using `natbib` package and these are the commands I am using

```
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
...
\bibliographystyle{ksfh_nat}
\bibliography{biblo}
```

Maybe it's got something to do with the `bibliographystyle`?

Comment: The hunch you expressed in the final sentence -- that it's got something to do with the bibliography style -- is correct. Are you free to choose a different bibliography style, or are you required to use `ksfh_nat`?

Comment: I am free to use bibliograpy style but i want it in this format

[1] Green, Don W. / Willhite, G. Paul (1998): SPE Textbook Series, Volume 6 :
Enhanced Oil Recovery. Richardson, TX, USA, Society of Petroleum Engineers.

Like auther first and date in brackets afterwards =/

Answer (score 1):

A comment up front: The `ksfh_nat` bibliography style appears to be quite buggy. For instance, in the example below, you'll see that for entries of type `@article` the issue number rather than the volume number is shown. Yikes!

Assuming you want to keep using this style, though, and merely want to replace the alphabetical sorting order for the typeset entries with the order in which the items are (first) cited in the body of the paper, you could proceed as follows:

- Find the file `ksfh_nat.bst` in your TeX distribution. Make a copy of this file and call the copy, say, `ksfh_unsrt.bst`.
- Open the file `ksfh_unsrt.bst` in a text editor. (The editor you use for your tex files will do fine).
- Near the bottom of the file -- on lines 1208 and 1210 in my copy of the file -- you find the instructions

  ```
  ITERATE {presort}

  SORT
  ```
- Comment out (or delete) both of these instructions.
- Save the file `ksfh_unsrt.bst`, either in the directory where your main tex file is located, or in a directory that's searched by your TeX distribution. If you choose the second option, be sure to update the filename database of your TeX distribution.
- Start using the modified bibliography style by replacing the instruction `\bibliographystyle{ksfh_nat}` with `\bibliographystyle{ksfh_unsrt}`. Be sure to re-run LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more to fully propagate all changes.

Happy BibTeXing!

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{ksfh_unsrt}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybibliography.bib}
@article{aaa,
   author  = "Anne Author",
   title   = "Thoughts",
   journal = "Circularity Today",
   year    = 3001,
   volume  = 1,
   number  = 2,
   pages   = "3--4",
}
@article{bbb,
   author  = "Bert Branson",
   title   = "Further Thoughts",
   journal = "Circularity Today",
   year    = 3002,
   volume  = 5,
   number  = 6,
   pages   = "7--8",
}
@article{jjj,
   author  = "Jack Handy",
   title   = "Deep Thoughts",
   journal = "Circularity Today",
   year    = 3003,
   volume  = 10,
   number  = 11,
   pages   = "12--13",
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\cite{jjj}, \cite{bbb}, \cite{aaa}
\bibliography{mybibliography}   
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for help... I am new to latex where do I find this file ksfh_nat.bst

Comment: @BakhtawarKhattak - The location of the file will depend on the TeX distribution you use. Can you open a command window and type "kpsewhich ksfh_nat.bst"?

Comment: omg thank you so much... i found it... i love u

Comment: I'm blushing...